# How to set UIcolor to deep blue

Tags: iphone, cocoa-touch, uikit

How can I set UIcolor to have a deepblue values (like 330099, shown in interface builder) programmatically?

Thanks.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

To create a UIColor based on RGB values you need to do:

```
[UIColor colorWithRed:0x33/255.0 green:0 blue:0x99/255.0 alpha:1.0]
```

Answer (score 4):

Just use Jeff LaMarche's UIColor extensions....

http://iphonedevelopment.blogspot.com/2008/11/more-colors-more-compact.html

and here:

http://iphonedevelopment.blogspot.com/2008/10/little-color-in-your-life.html

You can see how it is done.

Answer (score 1):

Or in stead of using 0x33 / 255.0 use the actual float for the color value, this of course requires you to convert the values.

```
[UIColor colorWithRed:51.0 / 255.0, green:0.0, blue:153.0 / 255.0];
```

As long as you use a floating point value in your division you don't have to cast anything. Make sure you use floating point values. For example: `33 / 255 = 0`. Which will become black.

Comment: Your example is confusing... 0x33 is 51 in Hex, not 33, that's why he should use 0x33.

Comment: You are right, I've adapted the example to use the correct values. I just wanted to point out that you don't have to use the hexadecimal values.

Answer (score 0):

Here is the best tool I have found yet! You can even set a hex color and have it auto generate the UIColor code for you.

http://uicolor.org/